# Is it possible to delay the launch of a spring-boot application until a Eureka registration has completed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have a spring-boot backend architecture which consists of a Eureka discovery service, a Zuul Gateway + various other microservices which register with the discovery service and communicate via the gateway.

One MS is a configuration service which is accessed by some of the other services via the gateway. This config service will have a request mapping for e.g. "/getOtherMicroserviceConfig", and will register with gateway as "config-service" so that "Other Microservice" will access *http://${gateway-url}/config-service/getOtherMicroserviceConfig* to retrieve its configuration.

In eclipse, I have configured a Launch group to start these with the dependencies as follows:

**discovery-service
- config-service
- gateway
- other-microservice**

Currently, I am only using "delay" (usually 30s) in the launch groups to allow adequate timings for each service to bootup before the next launches. However, I am finding that even though the first 3 services have all fully initialised before the last service is launched, registration with Eureka is neither immediate nor consistent - so 50% of the time "other-microservice" will fail to initialise with the following error seen in the gateway logs:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: config-service
```

Is there a way to delay initialisation of a microservice if a dependency registration has not completed?